# Why am I able to acces private attributes? Is it just eclipse? (C++)

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am doing a Klondike game in C++ and here is a class I have:

```
class Card
{
public:
    enum Kind
    {
        H   = 1,
        D   = 2,
        S   = 3,
        C   = 4
    };

    Card(Kind p_sorte, Value p_valeur);

    virtual ~Card();

private:
    Kind m_sorte;
    Value m_valeur;
};
```

I was wondering why eclipse would propose the two privates attributes in this context:

Klondike.h ->

```
#include "Card.h";
class Klondike
{
    Klondike();
}
```

Klondike.cpp ->

```
Klondike::Klondike()
{
    Card c = Card(H, ACE);
    cout << c.m_sorte;//THIS SHOULDN'T BE! But eclipse Is telling its fine?!?
}
```

Comment: what is this `Klondike();` in a header file?

Comment: Klondike is a kind of solitaire card game. This Is my constructor to my  controler (Larman)

Comment: A constructor doesn't live outside of a class

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki corrected

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say eclipse is telling you it's fine? Is it compiling?

Comment: @Sebastien Not quite, now there's a missing semi-colon. **Copy-paste** the code you have instead of typing it and making mistakes. Are you asking about Eclipse's code analyzer (Codan) not showing errors or are you saying your code compiles?

Comment: @Praetorian, Benjamin Lindley No it does not compile, but why does the code analyser says its ok?

Comment: @Sebastien It doesn't say it's ok, as the answer below says, there are visual cues that you're accessing a private member. There might be a way to ask it to not show inaccessible members, I'm not very familiar with Eclipse.

Comment: @Praetorian I am as much familiar with eclipse then you... In fact I am starting to really hate this IDE. I am force to use it for this project but god dammit it shows me red every where! if I save and it compile it goes away and everything is fine but the minute I type something everything goes red again...

Comment: @Praetorian you think the answer is bad?! If so, please explain. :)

Comment: @Praetorian sorry then, I just got tangled up with the comments. I will delete my comments shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is ***proposing*** them!

But that does not mean that they are able to be used. If you notice, they have a red sign on their left. They do so, so that the programmer has a complete view of the class.

[image]

Notice how `i` is marked with a green sign, because it's public, where `my_precious` is marked with a red sign, because it's private.

---

Of course, when I write:

```
a.my_precious;
```

I am getting this:

> error: ‘int A::my_precious’ is private

---

So, is it useless? Not really. Consider *friend classes*. In that case I would love to see the data members of the friend class when coding!

For example:

```
class Node 
{
    private: 
    int data;
    int key;
    // ...

    friend class BinaryTree; // class BinaryTree can now access data directly
};
```

taken from [Alex Allain](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/friends.html).

Comment: I find this weird, encapsulation is there to "hide" part of the implementation of a class, ain't it? So why show it? I guess I am just not use to code with Eclipse...

Comment: @Sebastien I had the same feeling when I first show this feature of Eclipse, so +1. Well encapsulation is not going to do much, since you have all the project in your hands! It tells you it is private with the red sign! However, for friend classes, this can be useful!

Comment: @Sebastien Encapsulation isn't there for the IDE. It's there for the compiler. Although IDEs can take advantage of it as well, seems Eclipse didn't.

Comment: @zenith Exactly! I think its weird that code analyser wouldn't hide private member outside there class... (AT gsamaras and show their friends when in the right context)

Comment: @Sebastien Well for friend classes, it's a nice feature. Otherwise I agree, *I think*. However, I am not an Eclipse developer. Maybe in their site you can leave some complaint about that feature and they will think about it. :)